# Tensorflow eval() without session or move variable to an other session

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow-models like it is described in the [iris predict examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/tflearn/index.html). Because of that I do not have a session object. Now I want to convert the labels to a numpy-array with `.eval()`. Without a session there comes an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "myfile.py", line 273, in <module>
   tf.app.run()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
   sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
 File "myfile.py", line 270, in main
   train_and_eval()
 File "myfile.py", line 258, in train_and_eval
   label.eval()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 559, in eval
   return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3642, in _eval_using_default_session
   raise ValueError("Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default "
ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`
```

Is there a possibility to access / get the session the model used in background? Or is there an other possibility to convert the tensor to a numpy-array?

If I create a new session, then it seems that tensorflow moves to this session but has no access to the variable. A python `print()` is displayed, but then it runs inifite. How can I parse a variable to this new session?

The other part of the net works well - it's only this special thing convert the tensor to a numpy-array

```
    COLUMNS = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "target"]
    LABEL_COLUMN = "target"
    CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]

    def build_estimator(model_dir):
        col1 = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket(
            "col1", hash_bucket_size=10000)
        col2........

        wide_columns = [col1, col2, col3]
        deep_columns = [
            tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(col1, dimension=7),
            tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(col2, dimension=7),
            tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(col3, dimension=7)
        ]

        m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(...)
        return m

    def input_fn(file_names, batch_size):
        ...
        label = tf.string_to_number(examples_dict[LABEL_COLUMN], out_type=tf.int32)
        return feature_cols, label

    def train_and_eval():
        model_dir = "./model/"
        print(model_dir)

        m = build_estimator(model_dir)
        m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train_file_name, batch_size), steps=steps)
        results = m.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(test_file_name, batch_size),
            steps=1)
        pred_m = m.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(test_file_name, batch_size))


        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        with sess.as_default():
            print("Is a session there?")
            _, label = input_fn(test_file_name, batch_size)
            label.eval()
            print(label)

    def main(_):
        train_and_eval()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        tf.app.run()
```

The new session starts at the end of the code-snippet:

```
        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        with sess.as_default():
            print("Is a session there?")
            _, label = input_fn(test_file_name, batch_size)
            label.eval()
            print(label)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a Session and you need to initialize your variables before being able to access them:

```
with Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    ...  
    label_numpy = label.eval()
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. But this does not work like it was asked. I can use the new session (this already worked with my code), but I do not have access to the variables of the other session. How can I pass them to the new session? Or alternatively how can I change my code / the iris predict example to use an explicit session or how can I get access to the default session of this code?

Comment: Did you ever find how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the order so as to solved my problem.

```
     import tensorflow as tf
     v= tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
     result = tf.clip_by_value(v, 2.5, 4.5).eval()
     with tf.Session() as sess:
          print(sess.run(result))
```

Then my IDE warned"ValueError: Cannot evaluate tensor using `eval()`: No default session is registered. Use `with sess.as_default()` or pass an explicit session to `eval(session=sess)`"

Afterwards, I changed it into:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    v= tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]])
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        result = tf.clip_by_value(v, 2.5, 4.5).eval()
        print(sess.run(result))
```

Then the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use an estimator you can evaluate this way :

```
 evaluate_result = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: my_input_fn(INPUT_FILE_PATH, BATCH_SIZE))
```

It will return a dict containing the evaluation metrics specified in model_fn keyed by name, as well as an entry global_step which contains the value of the global step for which this evaluation was performed.

Otherwise you can use a session in which you must initialize your global variables:

```
with Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

You will be able to evaluate the normal way and your session will have access to your model.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when I was trying to create some custom metrics/loss functions. What I ended up doing was to use `tf.py_func` or better `tf.py_function` to make a call to a python function. ([Tensorflow Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function)).

The tensors you pass into the function are expected to be turned into numpy data/arrays.
The only difference between `py_func` and `py_function` is that with `py_func` the Tensor is automatically turned into a numpy array, whereas with `py_function` it's still a Tensor and you have to manually call `.numpy()` on it.

Tensorflow will add this call to the graph execution for you.

```
def train_and_eval():
    ...
    with Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        ...
        labels = #some tensor
        other = #some tensor
        result = tf.py_function(some_function, [labels, other], [tf.float64]) # where the last argument
        # is an array representing the return type(s) of `some_function()`.
        # If `some_function` returns nothing, then you can do
        # tf.py_function(some_function, [labels, other], [])

# your normal python function
def some_function(labels, other):
    '''
    If you called this through py_func, the inputs are already numpy arrays,
    if you called through py_function, they're Tensors and you have to call
    labels.numpy() and other.numpy() to turn them to numpy.
    '''
    labels, other = labels.numpy(), other.numpy()
    print(labels)
```